# Why did this work? Printing an array in reversed order in MIPS

Tags: arrays, integer, mips, reverse

I have a project for class and everything was going fine. We just needed to store 20 integers from user input in an array and print them in various ways. My code worked printing it in the right order but when I did it in reverse, the output was pretty weird. So without understanding, I kinda got the gist the index was the issue and for some reason I solved it? But I don't understand if it's actually correct.

```
    # for reverse order that worked
    addi $t0, $zero, 76
    while:

        beq $t0, -4, exit

        lw $t1, inputArray($t0)

        li $v0, 1
        move $a0, $t1
        syscall

        li $v0, 4 
        la $a0, space
        syscall

        addi $t0, $t0, -4

        j while
```

Now here is what I did the first time:

```
     # reverse order that didn't work
     addi $t0, $zero, 76
     while:

        beq $t0, 0, exit

        lw $t1, inputArray($t0)

        li $v0, 1
        move $a0, $t1
        syscall

        li $v0, 4 
        la $a0, space
        syscall

        addi $t0, $t0, -4

        j while
```

The output for when it didn't work was:

1702129221 20 19 18 17 16 15 14 13 12 11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem even with your working code.

Indeed using `inputArray($t1)` is not the proper way to access your array. Your code will be *broken* if address of inputArray cannot be coded on 16 bits. And it makes your code harder to read and more error prone.

What you should do is to separate the loop counter and the array index computation. 
This roughly correspond to the following pseudo C code

```
for(int i=20, array=&inputArray[20]; i!=0; i--, array--){
  print(*array," ");
```

Asm version

```
    # init part :: int i=20, array=inputArray[20];
    addi $t0, $zero, 20   # $t0 is loop counter i
    li $t2, inputArray # load 32 bits address of inputArray $t2=@inputArray
    addi  $t2, 76         # $t2=array=@inputArray[20]
while:
    beq $t0, zero, exit   # loop condition :: i!=0;
    # loop body :: print  *Array, " "
    lw $t1, 0($t2)
    addi $v0,zero, 1
    move $a0, $t1
    syscall
    # print space
    addi $v0,zero, 4 
    li $a0, space
    syscall
    # loop increments :: i--, array--
    addi $t0, $t0, -1  #i--
    addi $t2, $t2, -4  #array--
    j while
```

Separating loop and array access always leads to better code. And is *much* simpler if you have to get different array elements per iteration, for instance, to print `array[i]*array[i-1]` or different array types `intArray[i]+=shortArray[i]`.

Your problem with the non working code was incorrect range check. With this kind of code, it cannot arrive if you start from a working C code.

Comment: Thanks, I made a simple mistake. Also, thank you for the great advice about separating the loop and array access. Will definitely keep that in mind.